# Google Analytics for android doesnt work from real device

Tags: android, google-analytics

I integrated the GoogleAnalyticsTracker following the instruction on the [official SDK page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html)
and run it on my AVD. Everything works and looks great.

However, after installing my app on a real device (galaxy s2) I noticed no statistics are generated at all. AVD works, real device doesn't (I can see access on the real-time dashboard)

Device has full internet access at all times
Any ideas?

[EDIT] Code included

myActivity

```
public void onCreate(...) {
  GoogleAnalyticsTracker t = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

  t.startNewSession("UA-xxxxxxxx-xx", this);
  t.setCustomVar(1, "somevar", "value2", 2);
  t.trackEvent("someevent", "startup", "desc", 2);
}

public void onPause(...) {
  GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().dispatch();
}
```

myView (on menu display)

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().trackPageView("/menu");
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs for any information about this issue?

Comment: For me analytics work on both emulator and real devices (including galaxy s2). It must be your fault :)

Comment: I can't see how it's my fault as I used the exact code taken from the SDK demo :( - I edited my question and included the code

Comment: i think no need to dispatch in onPause(), use tracker.stopSession on destroy() that is enough

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved...
It appears that my hosts file was modified by my custom ROM and that google analytics was blocked. 
Replacing it with a clean file solved the problem

Comment: Can you explain what "custom ROM" is?  I am having the exact same issue as your opening post.  My emulator is showing up on the Real Time on GA but not when I try on a device.